# SAS Reading multiple records from one line without Line Feed CRLF

Tags: import, sas, linefeed

I have only 1 line without line feed (CRLF CRLF), the linefeed is a string of 4 characters, in this example is "@A$3" I don't need dlm for now, and I need to import it from a external file (/files/Example.txt)

```
JOSH 30JUL1984 1011 SPANISH@A$3RACHEL 29OCT1986 1013 MATH@A$3JOHNATHAN 05JAN1985 1015 chemistry
```

I need this line into 3 lines:

```
JOSH 30JUL1984 1011 SPANISH
RACHEL 29OCT1986 1013 MATH
JOHNATHAN 05JAN1985 1015 chemistry
```

How I can do that in SAS?

*Added: Your solutions are working with this example, but i have a issue, a line that contains more than the maximum length allowed for the line(32,767 bytes),

For example this line in the  above exercise contains 5,000 records.

Is it possible?

Comment: If you're simply trying to read multiple records from one line of text, append "@@" to the end of the 'input' line, such as: *input column1 255. @@;*

Answer (score 2):

Use the `DLMSTR=` option on the `infile` statement -- this will specify "@A$3" as the delimiter.  Then use `@@` on the input statement to tell SAS to look for more records on the same line.

```
data test;
infile "/files/Example.txt" dsd dlmstr='@A$3';
informat var $255.;
input var $ @@;
run;
```

With your example, you will get a data set with 3 records with 1 variable containing the strings you are looking for.

Adjust the length of var as needed.

Comment: We had issues with `DLMSTR=`, it did not recognize  `@A$3@A$3` as a missing value. That was in SAS 9.2, maybe it's fixed now.

Comment: @DejanPeretin I had also thought of using `DLMSTR=` for specifying a multi-character delimiter, but it might not work across all versions. Hence, an alternative conversion method to single-char delimiter needs to be used. I think DomPazz's `DLMSTR=` should work fine for SAS 9.2 and newer since it was introduced in 9.2, but for 9.1.3 and older it would return as an error.

Comment: Found this: If there are consecutive delimiter strings in the file which indicate missing values, the DLMSTR= option will not read the file properly until SAS 9.3. Source: http://support.sas.com/kb/33/385.html

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

First import the file as a single row (be sure to adjust the length):

```
DATA WORK.IMPORTED_DATA;
INFILE "/files/Example.txt" TRUNCOVER;
LENGTH Column1 $ 255;
INPUT @1 Column1  $255.;
RUN;
```

Then parse imported data into variables using a data step:

```
data result (keep=var1-var4);
set  WORK.IMPORTED_DATA;

delim = '@A$3';
end = 1;
begin = 1;
do while (end > 0);

    end = find(Column1, delim, begin);
    row = substr(Column1, begin, end - begin);

    var1 = scan(row, 1);
    var2 = scan(row, 2);
    var3 = scan(row, 3);
    var4 = scan(row, 4);

    begin = end + length(delim);
    output;
end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in data step by viewing `@A$3` as a multi-character delimiter:

```
data want (keep=subject);
    infile 'C:\sasdata\test.txt';
    input;                                                     
    length line $4500  subject $80;
    line=tranwrd(_infile_,"@A$3",'!');         

    do i=1 by 1 while (scan(line,i,'!') ^= ' ');
        subject=scan(line,i,'!');                       
        output;
    end;
run;
```

`_infile_` gives the current row that is being read in the `data` step. I converted the multi-character delimiter `@A$2` into a single-character delimiter. `tranwrd()` can replace a sub-string inside a string. And then use the delimiter inside the `scan()` function.

Also, if you want to break the values up into separate variables, just scan some more. E.g. put something like `B = scan(subject,2);` into `do` loop and `data want (keep= A B C D);`. Cheers.